# Connecting button to an arbitrary function

Tags: c++, qt

Myself trying to write a program in Qt connecting a function to a button in Qt5.

```
 #include <QApplication>
 #include <QtGui>
 #include <QPushButton>
 static void insert()
 {
     qDebug() << “pressed”;
 }

 int main(int argc,char *argv[])
 {
     QApplication app(argc,argv);
     QPushButton *button=new QPushButton(“button”);
     button->setGeometry(50,100,150,80);
     QObject::connect(button,&QPushButton::clicked,insert());
     button->show();
  }
```

But I am getting errors like
    main.cc:23:39: error: within this context
    main.cc:23:55: error: invalid use of void expression
    make: *** [main.o] Error 1

Please help…

Comment: i do not know much about qt 5, but i think you need to remove the parathesis in `insert()` to `insert`.

Comment: i dont know about Qt but your function call `QObject::connect` doesnt match the prototype given here [Qt](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html).

Comment: Also, I doubt this will work without `return app.exec()` at the end of `main` function.

Answer (score 10):

In Qt 5, you need to use the new [qt signal and slots system](http://qt-project.org/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax). The connection will look like :

```
QObject::connect(button,&QPushButton::clicked,insert); <-- no parentheses.
```

It has already been stated, but you need to call `app.exec();` to start the event loop processing. Otherwise the connection will never be triggered.

Furthermore, if you are on release mode then you may not see the output of `qDebug()`

Comment: it throws out an error `spinBox: must be a class or namespace when followed by ::` even though I'm using Qt 5.4.

Answer (score 2):

***see edit below**

First of all you can not connect a signal to a function, you should connect it to a slot of some class, and an instance of this class should be provided to `QObject::connect` as well.

So the first thing to do is to define a class with a  slot:

```
// file 'C.h'
#ifndef __C_H__
#define __C_H__

#include <QtGui>

class C : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    static void insert()
    {
        qDebug() << "pressed";
    }
};

#endif
```

Note that this class have to inherit from `QObject` and to have `Q_OBJECT` keyword inside it.
You have to put this class declaration in a `*.h` file (you can not have `Q_OBJECT`'s in `*.cpp` files because Qt will not see it).

Now that you have a class with a slot, you can use `QObject::connect`, the proper way would be:

```
  QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), &c, SLOT(insert()));
```

Note that you have to use `SIGNAL()` macros for signals and `SLOT()` macros for slots when you connect them.

So the code in `main.cpp` should be as follows:

```
  #include "C.h"

  int main(int argc,char *argv[])
  {

      QApplication app(argc,argv);
      QPushButton *button=new QPushButton("button");
      button->setGeometry(50,100,150,80);
      C c;
      QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), &c, SLOT(insert()));
      button->show();

      return app.exec();
   }
```

You see how I provide an instance of a receiver object (`&c`) to `connect()` function, you have to do it even if your function is `static`.

And finally you have to `app.exec();` because otherwise your program will not have a message loop.

**EDIT:**

**I missed that the question was about Qt 5. For Qt 5.0 the answer is wrong.**

Comment: @UmNyobe Thank you. I totally missed that it was about Qt5.0