# Unable to connect signal to a function inside main()

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt4

I am aware that to use the signals and slots mechanism of Qt inside a class, the class must include the `Q_OBJECT` macro, but I am attempting to use signals and slots in `main()`, without using any class.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QtGui>

void saveText();

int main(int argv, char **args)
 {
    QApplication app(argv, args);
    QTextEdit textEdit;
    QPushButton saveButton("Save!");
    QPushButton exitButton("Exit!");
    QObject::connect(&exitButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),qApp,SLOT(quit()));
    QObject::connect(&saveButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),qApp,SLOT(saveText()));

    QVBoxLayout vlyt;
    vlyt.addWidget(&textEdit);
    vlyt.addWidget(&exitButton);
    vlyt.addWidget(&saveButton);

    QWidget mainWindow;
    mainWindow.setLayout(&vlyt);
    mainWindow.show();

    return app.exec();
}

void saveText()
{
    exit(0);
}
```

Here is the GUI window generated:

[image: GUI window]

From the above code, the exit button is connected to `quit()`, which is a Qt function, when clicked it works. The save button assigned to the function `saveText()`, is configured to exit, but does not do so.

Please tell me where I have gone wrong in understanding signals and slots in Qt.

Comment: connect(&saveButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [](){saveText();});  // qt5.9.6

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Qt4...

> All classes that inherit from QObject or one of its subclasses (e.g.,
>   QWidget) can contain signals and slots.[<sup>1</sup>](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html)

So, you **can not** use slots where placed outside of `QObject` children.

You can connect signals to the slots which are in classes where derived from `QObject`. Put your slot in a class which is in a separated *.h/.cpp* file:

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT

   ...

   public slots:
     void saveText();

};
```

According to Qt5: [New Signal Slot Syntax in Qt 5](http://qt-project.org/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax). You can connect to those type of global functions. (*Thanks to @thuga's comments*)

Comment: So why is exit button working ? Is the `quit() ` function inside of a class inheriting from QObject ?

Comment: `quit()` is a slot inside `qApp` and `qApp` is an object which derived from `QObject`.

Comment: You can do something like this in Qt5 though

Comment: @MM. [Here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax) it says `The new syntax can even connect to functions, not just QObjects`. You can also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16728197/connecting-button-to-an-arbitrary-function) question.

Comment: @thuga , thanks a lot man !! Wish you had given an answer , by editing my code to demonstrate it , but thanks anyways , the links have been of great help

Answer (score 4):

I'll just put example here.

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <QObject>
#include "siggen.h"

void handler(int val){
  std::cout << "got signal: " << val << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  SigGen siggen;
  QObject::connect(&siggen, &SigGen::sgAction, handler);
  siggen.action();

  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
  std::cout << "main prog start" << std::endl;

  return a.exec();
}
```

**siggen.h:**

```
#ifndef SIGGEN_H
#define SIGGEN_H

#include <QObject>

class SigGen : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  explicit SigGen(QObject *parent = 0);
  void action(void);

signals:
  void sgAction(int value);
};

#endif // SIGGEN_H
```

**siggen.cpp:**

```
#include "siggen.h"

SigGen::SigGen(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{}

void SigGen::action()
{
  emit sgAction(42);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
QObject::connect(&saveButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [](){saveText();});  // qt5.9.6
```

or as mentioned in the [masoud](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16734618/3096593)'s answer

```
QObject::connect(&saveButton, &QPushButton::clicked, saveText);  // qt5.9.6
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21954073)

Comment: "This does not provide an answer to the question." - what question ?

Comment: your answer is short it should be a comment, not an answer. please refer the guideline of StackOverflow.

Comment: @AashishJ *"your answer is short it should be a comment"* - Just because an answer is short doesn't mean it should be a comment, this is clearly an attempt to answer the question, whether or not it is correct is not the job of the LQP review queue,  that's what up/downvoting is for.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to connect a signal to function inside main function.
This has been tested in Qt5.15. Here is the simple example where the QPushButton 'Clicked' signal is used to trigger a function (here I used lamda's, but regular functions can also be used).

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Created QApplication
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    
    // Created the splashscreen(which is QObject)
    QPixmap pixmap(":/images/Sample.png");
    QSplashScreen splash(pixmap);

    // Created the pushbutton and added to splashscreen
    QPushButton b(&splash);
    b.setGeometry(50,50, 100, 50);
    b.setText("FPS");
    
    // variable to be modified inside a lamda function
    int i = 0;
    
    // Connection for button clicked signal executes lamda function
    QObject::connect(&b, &QPushButton::clicked, 
    [i = static_cast<const int&>(i), &splash = static_cast<QSplashScreen&>(splash)]()mutable 
    {i = i+1; splash.showMessage("clicked: "+ QString::number(i));});
    
    // Adding properties and displaying the splashscreen
    splash.setGeometry(0,0, 1920, 1080);
    splash.setEnabled(true);
    splash.show();
    
    a.processEvents();  
    return a.exec();
}
```